# How to assert that a type equals a given value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am writing a test for a method and I want to validate that the method returns a specific type. However, when I try this I get an error.

```
def search_emails(mail):  
  data = mail.uid('search')
  raw_email = data[0][1]  
  return raw_email
```

The type(raw_email) is: `<class 'bytes'>`

When I run this test:

```
def test_search_emails_returns_bytes():  
  result = email_handler.search_emails(mail)
  assert type(result) == "<class 'bytes'>"
```

I get this error. How can I state the assertion so the test will pass? Or is there a better way to write the test?

```
E       assert <class 'bytes'> == "<class 'bytes'>"
```

Comment: `assert type(result) is bytes` or `assert isinstance(result, bytes)`

Comment: `isinstance(result, bytes)`

Comment: You're comparing an actual `type` object with a string object.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use the `is` operator to check that a variable is of a specific type

```
my_var = 'hello world'
assert type(my_var) is str
```

Answer (score 18):

You need to use isinstance, its a built in function for type checking

```
def test_search_emails_returns_bytes():  
  result = email_handler.search_emails(mail)
  assert isinstance(result, bytes)
```

Comment: In some cases it could be important to prefer `isinstance(X, Y)` to `type(X) is Y` as `isinstance` also returns `True` for subclasses.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to check that something is specifically of a class, isinstance won't do, because that will return True even if it is a derived class, not exactly the class you want to check against. You can get the type as a string like this:

```
def decide_type(raw_prop):
    """Returns the name of a type of an object.
    Keep in mind, type(type("a")) is Type,
                  type(type("a").__name__) is Str
    """
    type_as_string = type(first_raw_prop).__name__
    return type_as_string
```

That will actually return 'lst', 'int', and such.

In your code, that'd translate to something like this:

```
assert type(result).__name__ == "bytes"
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you mentioned that you are using a *method*, then, `assertIsInstance` might be handy:

```
import unittest

def myfunc(name):
    return type(name)

class TestSum(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_type(self):
        result = myfunc('Micheal')
        self.assertIsInstance(result, str)

unittest.main()
```

For a list of assert methods, scroll down [here](https://realpython.com/python-testing/#writing-your-first-test):

Comment: It's not only handy, this is the preferred way, in my opinion

Answer (score 3):

Feel free to disagree, but this version eliminates any ambiguity over what the type your variable evaluates to:

```
result = "text"
self.assertEqual(type(result),type("text"))
```

Comment: I think this solution is simplest and easy.